# I need help on creating a name changing program

Tags: python, function, project, output

This question is for a school project so don't give my exact answer  XD
But please tell me how I would start it. I have been trying it for a couple of hours but I just can't get it. Here is the question:

Create a function in python that accepts names in standard form and prints them in the form:

E.g. INPUT                               to           OUTPUT
Santa Claus                               to           Claus, S.
Michael J. Fox                            to           Fox, M. J.
Madonna                                   to           Madonna
William Henry Richard Charles Windsor     to           Windsor, W. H. R. C.

Comment: You must  learn regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need a function that takes in a name, e.g.

```
def convert_name( name ):
```

Then I think you want to split the name into the first, last, and middle names (if applicable):

```
subnames = name.split() # split the name on whitespace
```

After that, you should check the various cases of what is contained in subnames. Using Madonna as an example, one case could be

```
if (len(subnames) == 1): return subnames[0]
```

Hope that helps get you started!

Answer (score 0):

You will need an algorithm, which separates your input string by whitespaces. Then you would take the last of those separated strings and add it to your output string. You will have to add a comma, if more names are following. After that, take the other strings, starting with the first one, and check if they are already in the form "[A-Z].". If not, transform them to that form. Otherwise just add them to your output. Thats it. I could be more precise, but you asked not to be :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then use `String.Split()` To change String into List , then use `len()` to count the elements. Use loop `for` and create new string .